# SqlParameter Output returns null

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, .net-core, parameters

I have a stored procedure that lists items starting at an `@index` and returns the next `@length` items. In addition, an `@available` `Output` parameter returns the count of items in the set.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.List
    @index int = 0,
    @lenth int = 10,
    @available int OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.table1 WHERE ...;
    @available = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.table1);
END
```

`table1` contains 12 rows.

I run some.NET code (C#) using `System.Data.SqlClient` to get the data:

```
await using var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=...");

await connection.OpenAsync();

await using var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.List", connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("index", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 0 });
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("length", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 3 });

var outParam = new SqlParameter("available", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

command.Parameters.Add(outParam);

await using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

while (await reader.ReadAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["Name"]);
}

Console.WriteLine("Available items: " + outParam.Value + " rows");
```

This outputs something like

```
Joe
Anne
Raj
Available items:  rows
```

For some reason the `outParam.Value` returns `null`, while the expected result is 12.

Anyone have insight into what is going on here? Where did my "rows count" go?

Comment: Is `available =` supposed to be  `@available =`?

Comment: also you have to name your `SqlParameter` to be what sql expects. Your proc uses `@available` and your `SqlParameter` is targeting "AvailableItems"

Comment: @Xedni Both `@available*` and `available` work - it's actually respecting the `lenght`and `index` parameters fine  ;)  Also, I messed up my "anonymization" of the code so `AvailableItems` was a misrepresentation, fixed that. Incidentally, it will complain at `ExecuteReaderAsync` if any paramters are misnamed or missing.

Comment: I meant on the sql side

Comment: Oh, that. Typo in the "anonymized" version. The actual code uses the correctly typed parameter name (or else it wouldn't have validate or run)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter name passed to `SqlParameter` ctor should match the one of the stored procedure, try changing the code to:

```
var outParam = new SqlParameter("@available", SqlDbType.Int) 
{ 
   Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
};
```

Also AFAIK reader should be closed so the output parameter can be processed. One way to fix this is to switch from `using` declaration (which will result in reader being disposed at the end of the holding scope, i.e. after `outParam` is accessed) to `using` statement:

```
await using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
{
    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader["Name"]);
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("Available items: " + outParam.Value + " rows");
```

Comment: That, unfortunately, does not solve it. In fact, messing around with the snippet to purposefully use mismatchrd names cause the ExexuteReaderAsync to fail, complaining that invalid parameter names are used. In the straightforward version, the SQL statement executes, it gets the rows, but the output parameter value is null even if it runs fine with the right results in sql manager studio.

Comment: @SigurdGarshol ATM I don't have set up to repro so I will try it tomorrow. As fro now try the parameter with `@` and also you can try accessing it the following way after the query execution - `cmd.Parameters["@available"].Value`

Comment: Thanks, that actually solved it. I assume this means that, while the reader is not closed & disposed, the command isn't able to populate, or just isn't proceeding with populating, the output parameters. I feel this is a bit unintuitive, but watcha gonna do? I guess this is just the sort of code I need to slap a "don't change!" comment on so the next guy doesn't come along and inadvertently breaks it by cleaning it up to a prettier-looking *using* declaration...

Comment: @SigurdGarshol was glad to help! Explicit call to `Close` can be also a fix but it suffers from the same issue - comment will be required.

Answer (score -1):

**ExecuteReaderAsync vs ExecuteNonQueryAsync**

If your query returns a result set and you want to read that result set, you use ExecuteReaderAsync. If your query does not return a result set or if you only want to obtain a value such as the affected row count, you use ExecuteNonQueryAsync.

```csharp
var outParam = new SqlParameter("available", SqlDbType.Int) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };

command.Parameters.Add(outParam);

//await using var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

//while (await reader.ReadAsync())
//{
//  Console.WriteLine(reader["Name"]);
//}

await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Available items: " + outParam.Value + " rows");
```